# Select a table if boolean is true - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a main table called `Delivery` in my SQL Server database and 6 different roles saved in Active Directory.

Each role needs to see the same table but with different values, and a person may have multiple roles.

I'm trying to build a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns the table by their roles.

I have different functions that return the table by a user role, let's call them:

```
GetRole1Deliveries()
GetRole2Deliveries()
GetRole3Deliveries()
GetRole4Deliveries()
GetRole5Deliveries()
GetRole6Deliveries()
```

I built a procedure that gets a boolean (bit) value for each role as a parameter,
and I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDeliveriesByRole] (@p_role1 bit,@p_role2 bit,@p_role3 bit,@p_role4 bit@p_role5 bit,@p_role6 bit)

AS
BEGIN

if @p_role1=1 select * from GetRole1Deliveries();
union
if @p_role2=1 select * from GetRole2Deliveries();
union
if @p_role3=1 select * from GetRole3Deliveries();
union
if @p_role4=1 select * from GetRole4Deliveries();
union
if @p_role5=1 select * from GetRole5Deliveries();
union
if @p_role6=1 select * from GetRole6Deliveries();



END
```

can anybody help me get it to work?

Comment: If someone has multiple roles, what should they therefore see? Having different objects for this seems like bad idea.

Comment: @Larnu what do you mean? for example if user has roles 1 and 2 they see rows that Role1 should see, and rows that roles2 should see all together

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: I would just change the `GetRoleXDeliveries` function to pass in the `@p_role`

Comment: @Squirrel that would return only one role Deliveries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a single query:

```
select * from GetRole1Deliveries() where @p_role1 = 1
union
select * from GetRole2Deliveries() where @p_role2 = 1
union
select * from GetRole3Deliveries() where @p_role3 = 1
union
select * from GetRole4Deliveries() where @p_role4 = 1
union
select * from GetRole5Deliveries() where @p_role5 = 1;
```

This assumes that all the functions return the same columns with the same order and with compatible types.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, can't believe i didn't found this by myself, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Other alternative is use a temp variable table

```
DECLARE @Result table ([id] int, [desc] nvarchar(400)) --same estructure of result table

IF (@p_role1 = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT @Result
    SELECT 1, 'role 1'
END
IF (@p_role2 = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT @Result
    SELECT 2, 'role 2'
END
IF (@p_role3 = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT @Result
    SELECT 3, 'role 3'
END
IF (@p_role4 = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT @Result
    SELECT 4, 'role 4'
END
IF (@p_role5 = 1)
BEGIN
    INSERT @Result
    SELECT 5, 'role 5'
END

SELECT [Id], [desc]
FROM @Result
```